# Is the inverted pi a standard symbol for d-separation?

Tags: conditional-probability, notation, density-estimation

I've seen the inverted pi symbol earlier but found it hard to find an explanation for it. Found it again in the context of d-separation between Xu and Xv here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network#d-separation

To confirm this and for anyone who later searches for "inverted pi", could anyone confirm that it is a symbol specifically for d-separation or is it a general symbol to indicate separation between two PDF's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that $ X\perp \!\!\!\perp Y$ just denotes independence between the variables $X$ & $Y$. Conditional independence between $X$ & $Y$ given $Z$ is usually written as $ X\perp \!\!\!\perp Y | Z$.

[Reference: Notation in probability and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_in_probability_and_statistics)